# Xcode4 commit message - how to turn of auto-correction

Tags: xcode4

Can it be turned off ? If yes: how ?

For instance it keeps changing "refactor" to "refractor".
When i correct it - Xcode changes it back (oO).

Comment: I think this is a system (Mac) setting, not Xcode setting.

Comment: @kennyTM: any idea where this option could be. Did not find anything in system preferences and only obscure threads on google for other apps like safari and TextEdit and some for a new auto correct feature in Lion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look in System Preferences, Languages and text, Text tab, there is a checkbox for auto-correction.

Comment: Thank you. I did look in that tab before. But did not realize the setting is hidden behind the dropdown list of "Spelling: Automatic by Language"

Comment: np. I looked for that high and low : whenever i would put a snarky remark on POSish Xcode, it would render it politically correct. When in a really foul mood with the tool, i would sometimes revert to french, you should see some of my 'auto corrected' commit statements.

Comment: In case anyone else is using another language.. it is the section with the keyboard icon.